# Firebase auto save Timestamp -flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

i build a chat app using flutter and i save each message with datetime of unitime and thats ok
now when i tested the app on 2 devices the have 2 min difference so this caused a problem  that the messages was not displayed correctly couse there is a difference in time

Is there was to let firebase saves the current server time (**of firebase itself**)
thanks

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()